# how to join inventory items in a comma delimited list?

Tags: ansible, join, template

I have ansbile inv

```
# cat inv
[all]
vm1
vm2
```

I want to extract them in a comma delimited list using Jinja template

so I add jinja template

```
# cat comb_list.j2

{{ groups['all'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['item']) | join(',') }}"
```

but I guess item is not a hostvars, so throws error

I want end file to look like this

```
# cat comb_list
vm1,vm2
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697186/creating-a-user-with-password-in-ansible-playbook-in-ubuntu check this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template

```yaml
shell> cat comb_list.j2
{{ groups.all|join(',') }}
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: comb_list.j2
        dest: comb_list
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i inv playbook.yml
...

shell> cat comb_list
vm1,vm2
```